# Bootstrap Toast does not auto hide until I hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, toast

Bootstrap Toaster on react does not hide automatically after the delay until I hover the toaster. Anyone else has similar issue? Am I missing something in my code?

Here is the issue on code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-blackwell-04f0x5?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

The toasts are not hiding on their own because of this class  `className="toast fade show"`. WHen you hover it this class becomes  `className="toast fade hide"`.

So technically, you should not hardcode this `show` class and instead call the `toastObj.show()` manually and I guess that should solve the problem.